# How to write variable value to text file in a SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure without using BCP or xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to write into a text file a variable's value in a SQL Server stored procedure without using `BCP` or `xp_cmdshell`. I do not want to use linked server either or write .NET code and upload the DLL into SQL Server.

Please suggested some other straight forward means.

Say

```
SET @AFFECTEDAPPS = @AFFECTEDAPPS + CONVERT(varchar(20),@APP_KEY) + ', '
-- Now i just want to write @AFFECTEDAPPS to a text file on the server.
```

Comment: To do this, use `bcp` or `xp_cmdshell` - both will work. Not clear why you're excluding the two approaches that work the best upfront..... SQL Server is a **data management** system - it doesn't have an extensive file-oriented interface - other than `bcp` and `xp_cmdshell` .....

Comment: thank you for the response marc_s. Our company has indicated that they have disabled xp_cmdshell for security reasons. Any other approach would help me a lot! Thanks!